# How to add back button event in Universal Windows App without using WinjS Library?

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10-universal

This is my main.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

//No need of WinJS
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
var roaming = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingSettings;

// For App Start Up
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
    if (args.detail[0].kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (roaming.values["currentUri"]) {
            if (roaming.values["UserName"])
            {
                localStorage.setItem("UserName", roaming.values["UserName"]);
                window.location.href = roaming.values["currentUri"];
            }
        }
    }
});

// For App Suspension
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("suspending", function (args) {
    roaming.values["currentUri"] = window.location.href;
    roaming.values["UserName"] = localStorage.getItem("UserName");
});

// For Resuming App
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", function (args) {
    var roam = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingSettings;
    if (roam) {
        if (roam.values["currentUri"]) {
            localStorage.setItem("UserName", roam.values["UserName"]);
            window.location.href = roam.values["currentUri"];
        }
    }
}, false);
// not working backpressed event
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("backpressed", function (args) {
   // to do
}, false);})();
```

I need to add back key press event for windows phone without using winjs library?
Can anyone suggest me?

I am using ms-appx-web context in my app. I dont want to use winjs library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add back key press event for windows phone without using winjs library?

The `backpressed` event should be attached to `Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons` but not `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication`.

If you refer to [HardwareButtons.BackPressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1) and [HardwareButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1), you will find the `backpressed` event is used like this:

```
var hardwareButtons = Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons;
function onBackPressed(eventArgs) { /* Your code */ }

// addEventListener syntax
hardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", onBackPressed);
hardwareButtons.removeEventListener("backpressed", onBackPressed);
```

And since you are not making a Single Page Application. This event should be attached on every new page's JS codes.

**Update:** If you want to know your current device programmatically, you can use the following if-statement:

```
if (deviceInfo.operatingSystem.toLowerCase() == "windowsphone")
{
     //do your windows phone logic
} else if (deviceInfo.operatingSystem.toLowerCase() == "windows")
{
     //do your windows logic
}
```

Comment: In line `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication` it shows **JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined or null reference** error when I run desktop app. So I need solution for that. 
It shows `WIndows.Phone` undefined.

Comment: Is there any exit event for app?

Comment: I can't reproduce the null error, maybe share a demo? There is no exit event for app. But everytime your app exit, it will suspend first then exit. So you can do your logic in suspend event.

Comment: I cannot...but only thing I can tell is I am unable to access Windows.Phone namespace even intellitrace is also not showing it.

Comment: Do i need to add reference for it in solution.

Comment: When I run my universal app on phone it works fine but when I am running on desktop (same app) it shows this null reference error?

Comment: Can I add something to main.js to detect whether app is opening in desktop or mobile?

Comment: Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 0):

I used this-

```
var flag = Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.isTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");

    if (flag) {
        var hardwareButtons = Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons;
        hardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", onBackPressed);
    }
```

It worked for me well!